# php based calling App

Tags: php, web, call, p2p

We are developing a web app to let site-user call each other through our portal. it an e-learning portal so we want to let tutors communicate only through our portal for some privacy reasons. so I want to know whether is it possible to build such an app and how, coz our developers say that "it is not practicable without buying a VoIP or SIP service. we can't do it on our own behalf."

Answer (score 0):

You can have a developer build a solution around WebRTC. This technology allows audio and even video chats through the browser, without the need for a 3rd party provider. It does require users to have modern browsers.

See [Firefox Hello page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hello-video-and-voice-conversations-online) to get some ideas.

However, I'm not sure this will meet your privacy requirements. In other words, the users will be able to communicate directly without you once your portal puts them in touch with each other.

Comment: Thanks BeetleJuice for the comment. But their recommendation is not about WebRTC "it needs complexe and heavy development. do you have any idea how long will it take to develop if we start on WebRTC? for audio video communication?